# Add a checkbox in a table cell when using ngFor to parse two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a two dimensional array.

```
 var arr = [
            { ID: 1, Name: "foo", Email: "foo@foo.com", isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: 2, Name: "bar", Email: "bar@bar.com", isChecked: "true" }               
        ]
```

So the I want to display the data in the table.

```
this.tableData = arr.map(function (obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
                return obj[key];
            });
        });
```

I use `ngFor`.

```
<table class='table' *ngIf="tableData">
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData;">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of data">
          {{ cell['name'] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want more, I want to add checkbox beside the text in cells. What I tried:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of tableData;">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of data">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="cell['isChecked']">
      {{ cell['name'] }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the ckeckbox is not shown.

Comment: You're missing the closing tag on the input element.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. I added it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You start off with a 1-dimensional array - `arr`, and convert each object into an array to make a 2-dimensional array - `tableData`. You then loop over each array in `tableData`, trying to refer to object properties by name when in fact you have an array. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @KurtHamilton, I think that is a two-dimensional array. The data was from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978183/using-an-ngfor-to-traverse-a-2-dimensional-array. I just added a more column `isChecked`. The original question didn't have a checkbox but I want it.

Comment: `arr` is 1-dimensional. But that's not the point - what are you trying to achieve? A table with a row per element in `arr`, where each row contains a cell with a checkbox and a cell with the name?

Comment: `tableData` is 2-dimensional, as it's an array of arrays. You have taken the answer to that question, which is looping over the nested arrays, but you're now also trying to use object property keys - which don't exist in either level of your 2D array.

Comment: What I want is inside the cell, usually it shows a text. That is fine. But I want text and a checkbox side by side in the cell. In other word, put them together.@KurtHamilton

Comment: So just the text from `name` and the checkbox for `isChecked`?

Comment: Yes, something like. We can say I want to place the label right besides the checkbox in the same cell. Thecheck box is checked if the bool value is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clarified that you want to display one row for each element in `arr`. Each table row should display the element `Name` and a checkbox for the element `isChecked` property.

To achieve this you don't need to create the 2-dimensional `tableData` array that you have created, you can just loop over `arr`. You can bind to `isChecked` using `[(ngModel)]`.

You also don't need a table, as you only have one "thing" per row. You can easily apply this technique to a table if you wish to though.

component.ts

```js
arr = [
  { ID: 1, Name: "foo", Email: "foo@foo.com", isChecked: true },
  { ID: 2, Name: "bar", Email: "bar@bar.com", isChecked: false }             
];
```

component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of arr">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.isChecked">
    {{ data.Name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzxcgq

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure why the checkbox is not bind in Angular 5 when I use `ngModel`.  The input is in a Form of course. You used Angular 8 in the stackbliz.

Comment: There's no reason for it not to work in Angular 5 - it's using fundamental techniques that have been around for a long time. In Angular 5: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx5le1

Comment: I am not exactly sure. My code is a little different from you. I put the data in table element then I put ngFor in tr element. Input element in td element, is it right?

Comment: Why don't you create a stackblitz? For my v5 version if you want.